# P-CSCF is adding an extra paramater ( i=1) in the via header field before forward the registration request to next hop

Tags: sip, kamailio, ims

Generate a registration request from TP-2000  and P-CSCF successfully accept the request and add its own entry in the via header field  before forwarding the request to wards the I-CSCF.

P-CSCF should not add any junk field to the via header field

Expected :

```
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 
10.193.30.10;branch=z9hG4bK71d3.710ba3847d1301c016f10c7c7b5f8864.0`
```

Observation:
P-CSCF is adding an extra parameter in the via header field

```
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 
10.193.30.10;branch=z9hG4bK71d3.710ba3847d1301c016f10c7c7b5f8864.0;i=1
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the question here. You have shared a observation.

If your question is validity of the addition - I haven't seen a requirement in IMS / RFC specs that says the PCSCF should not be adding generic [junk??] parameter to Via.

A name-value generic param can be added to the Via and its unto the end points to decide the behavior based on it.

Comment: In the observation, we can see i=1, sometimes the result is i=5.
my doubt is : whether " i " is extra parameter in via header? will it cause any problem?

Comment: Any header param that doesn't interfere with basic ABNF of the Via Param should be ignored - Since its outside the ";" it makes it a Header param and can be ignored by the parser.